# LMR33630A, my built circuit doesn't match the expected output

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, troubleshooting

Using TI's "power designer", I've taken their 33630A and designed it for a 5v output. My actual circuit has a slightly different value for the divider to raise the voltage up to about 5.2v, otherwise it matches this design:

[image: TI circuit designer]

..and here's my design. I've reviewed it a few times.

[image: my circuit]

[My circuit, and the PCB from it, are on easyeda](https://easyeda.com/tedder/lmr33630a-breakout). After assembling the circuit, my output is right around 1 volt and the chip is overheating. I can't figure out why! I've checked for short circuits, and I've done in-circuit tests to ensure the passives are approximately correct.

As a wanna-be-EE, I don't know where to go next. I have [a low-end 'scope](https://pokitmeter.com/) and a high-end meter. I'm not using this attached to anything (e.g., it isn't actually connected to a Raspberry Pi), and I'm supplying it with 12-16v. I also removed LED1 so I could rule that part of the circuit out.

Comment: Unrelated to anything, that "pokitmeter" thing looks like a handy thing for hobbyists dipping their toes into EE. Thanks for inadvertently bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be the answer for this specific problem: Double-check that the pad really is soldered down. All kinds of Bad Things could happen without that analog reference being where it belongs.

Going out one layer; when you're working with a prototype you can't assume that a problem is either a design issue (anywhere, schematic or PCB in this case) or an assembly issue.  You have to check both.  With assembly issues, you have to check everything -- it's easy to get a soldered connection wrong and have it look right.  After doing it for a while you come to be an expert at noticing the subtle hints, but it doesn't come quickly.  Any soldered connection that's hidden (like a BGA, or those thermal pads) is especially difficult.  It's not uncommon for circuit board houses to x-ray boards to verify that all balls on a part are soldered, and that complete coverage between chip pad and PCB has been attained.

Answer (score 4):

You appear to be using a nice beefy inductor, so you've avoided that common noob mistake.

But layout is important for these switchers and yours doesn't much resemble the [LMR33630EVM](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/snvu573a/snvu573a.pdf) - particularly the trace between the IC and inductor, and inductor & output filter caps (which should all be short & fat).
Similarly, your input caps are too "far away" from the IC - in particular look at the path between pin-1 and the ground pins on those caps - it goes all the way around the edge of your board. Lots of vias would probably help a bit here, but rearranging things to bring them physically closer together with more direct routing would help more.

Comment: Thanks. I originally had one that was very close to the spec sheet's pattern but was part of a larger circuit. This was my simplified board to see if I could get it working in isolation. While I wouldn't expect it to be perfect, I wouldn't expect it to outright fail like this.

Comment: I agree with this, the OP should look at the switch node on a scope to see what's going on.  Also could get closer to 5.2V output with 150K and 35.7K divider resistors.  (Can find optimal divider resistors and output tolerance range at http://www.syncbuck.com )

Comment: Also double-check that the pad really is soldered down.  All kinds of Bad Things could happen without that analog reference being where it belongs.

Comment: thanks all. I'll look at the SW pin and also make up another PCB in the next 24 hours; AGND could very well be the culprit, as I've desoldered and resoldered the 33630 chip on this PCB. If AGND was floating would that explain the chip overheating too?

Comment: the problem was *definitely* AGND. Now that my second try is working, [I see the switch node going from 0-2V](https://imgur.com/pFLR2Mr) and [the inductor is bouncing about 0-8v](https://imgur.com/qGZM19o).  So I definitely need to rearrange, but ultimately @TimWescott is correct (please post an answer..).